# How to reduce the time of curl call?

Tags: php, curl

For some reason my curl call is very slow. Here is the code I used.

```
            $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Expect:','Accept: application/xml'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        //curl_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, !($options['return_body']));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS,0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $curl_error = curl_error($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
```

we have 9000 records to fetch
its taking 56 mins

To check execution time for each record I use curl_getinfo() function;
and each record take ~0.46 seconds!!

I want to reduce this seconds.

any luck it can reduce to 15 mins?

Comment: have tried check the response time in any other way?  like grab one record with curl-cli or wget?

Comment: You can use asynchronous call - `http://www.waytoblogger.com/2014/01/12/how-to-make-asynchronous-rest-call-using-curl-in-php/` - this might help you.

Comment: You can't really "reduce the time", it is up to the remote server to determine when it will respond.

Comment: http://www.waytoblogger.com/2014/01/12/how-to-make-asynchronous-rest-call-using‌​-curl-in-php/ link not opening @prava

Comment: http://www.waytoblogger.com/2014/01/12/how-to-make-asynchronous-rest-call-using-curl-in-php/

Comment: if your curl requests are independant of each other then have you considered running them in parallel using multiple, separate instances of the php script?

Comment: tried with asynchronous but not luck @prava

Answer (score 0):

Try to set one more cURL option.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Also try to use `curl_multi_exec`.

Answer (score 0):

Use file_get_contents($url)

example with User Agent

```
<?php
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
?>
```

Comment: Why `file_get_contents` over `curl`?